# Return nth line from (current) buffer

Tags: buffers, string

I want to get the first line of the buffer I'm actually in. More generally, I'm looking for a utility that returns Nth line from a supplied buffer. Is there some built-in for that?

Comment: FWIW, this operation is not provided by any built-in, because it's not something you'd normally ever need.  So I suspect that there's another way to do what you want which does not require such an operation.

Comment: @Stefan I want to do something with data in file, and for that I need some information that is stored in the first line.

Comment: That much I could guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done with the next function (with or without narrowing):

```
(defun get-nth-line (number)
  "Get line with NUMBER"
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-line number)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position)
                                      (line-end-position)))))
```

To get the first line execute

```
(get-nth-line 1)
```

If you want to get text properties, then use `buffer-substring` instead of `buffer-substring-no-properties`.